# PHP fwrite function why i cannot write "$" character in fwrite

Tags: php, character, fwrite

What is the problem in this code? Why cannot I use "$" in fwrite function?

```
fwrite($dosya_index,"$al_".$bol_radiopart[1]." = $_POST['".$bol_radiopart[1]."'];");
```

Comment: If you want a literal `$` then put it in single quotes, otherwise PHP will assume that you're trying to write a variable value

Answer (score 2):

This is because PHP variables are [*interpolated*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_interpolation) in strings enclosed with double quotes. This means that words starting with the `$` sign in double quotes will be handled as variables, and if such variable exists, its value is replaced within the string. Escape the $ sign (`\$`) or use single quotes where interpolation is not applied.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure what you trying to achieve, but i guess you're trying to write some code into a file or something.
If you wanna use $ and such you've to use ' instead of ", like this:

```
fwrite($dosya_index,'$al_' . $bol_radiopart[1] . ' = $_POST[' . $bol_radiopart[1] . '];');
```

Answer (score 0):

See this example:

```
//$write is a handler for the fopen() method you can use any $var you want and encode info too before execute
      $write=fopen($filepath,"w") or die ('Something went wrong'); // "w" flag is for read and write mode, create file if doesn't exists and delete file content before write
      fwrite($write, $filecontent); //write all data saved in the string "$filecontent" into the file
      fclose($write); // close the file
```

read more at: https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.fwrite.php

Comment: You need a handler like $write in the example